# How do I pass a variable from a pipeline task into a terraform task and apply it in my terraform code?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform, azure-pipelines

So I have a pipeline with a task, where I check for the date through Powershell.

```
 - task: PowerShell@2
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          $iso8601_time = Get-Date -Format "o"
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=pitr_time;]$iso8601_time"
        displayName: "Get point-in-time record before launching migration"
```

I am trying to use this date later in my terraform task to create a database based on the DateTime from my PowerShell task.

If I got it correctly with the use of

```
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=pitr_time;]$iso8601_time"
```

I create an environment variable with the name pitr_time that could be passed on to other tasks within the same pipeline.

Thus, I now have a second task where I use this environment variable.

```
- stage: DeployInfraPOC
  dependsOn: BuildInfraPOC
  variables:
    env: poc
    # TODO: check if variable get transfered to tf.
    TF_VAR_PITR: $(pitr_time)
  jobs: 
  - template: templates/deploy-infra.yml
    parameters:
      env: poc
      armServiceConnection: "Service connection devops"
      projectRoot: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
      planArtifactName: "pitr-database-migration-poc-$(Build.BuildId).tfplan
```

Now, when I checked the terraform documentation, I saw that I had to define it using the prefix "TF_VAR_" to use the variable I want to pass.

But now my question is: how can I use this variable in Terraform?

I thought I could just add it inside my variables.tf file as

```
variable "TF_VAR_PITR" {
  description = "Env var - Point-in-time restore."
  type = string
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work when I want to call my variable inside my main.tf like this

```
resource "azurerm_mssql_database" "mssqldb" {
  name                          = "db-bkup-temp-pitr"
  server_id                     = data.azurerm_mssql_server.mssqlsrv.id
  create_mode                   = "PointInTimeRestore"
  creation_source_database_id   = "/subscriptions/##############"
  restore_point_in_time         = var.TF_VAR_PITR
  }
```

What am I doing wrong? Are there better alternatives?

Comment: Variables are not shared across stages unless they are output variables and referenced using specific syntax. Refer to the documentation on variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your env variable is `TF_VAR_PITR`, then the TF variable is called `PITR`:

```
variable "PITR" {
  description = "Env var - Point-in-time restore."
  type = string
}
```

Comment: Does not work, I still get:
│ Error: expected "restore_point_in_time" to be a valid RFC3339 date, got "$(pitr_time)": parsing time "$(pitr_time)" as "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00": cannot parse "$(pitr_time)" as "2006"
│ 
│   with azurerm_mssql_database.mssqldb,
│   on main.tf line 17, in resource "azurerm_mssql_database" "mssqldb":
│   17:   restore_point_in_time         = var.PITR

Comment: @PrayingMantis This is new issue  then what you posted. Now the problem is about proper formating of timestamp, not about accessing your variable. Thus new question should be made with relevant details, such as, what actually is your PITR.